# If hover from right then animate right to left and reversed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found this fancy site:
http://www.lapierrequitourne.com/
I like the navigation and would like to use something like that on my website.

I dont know how to animate the width from right to left and how to check on which side the mouse leaves.

atm ive got the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#navi li").hover(function(e) {
        if ((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < $(this).width() / 2) {
            //left
        } else {
            //right
        }
    }, function(e) {

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="navi">
        <ul>
            <li>MENU ITEM</li> <!-- hover element -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="hv"></div> <!-- slide element -->
</div>
```

1. [**jQuery UI:**](https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/)

   You can use `jQuery-UI` which has support for directions in slide:

   ```
   $("#navi li").hover(function (e) {
       if ((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < $(this).width() / 2)
           $('#hv').show("slide", {direction: "left"});
       else
           $('#hv').show("slide", {direction: "right"});
   }, function (e) {
       if ((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < $(this).width() / 2)
           $('#hv').hide("slide", {direction: "left"});
       else
           $('#hv').hide("slide", {direction: "right"});
   });
   ```

   [**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/gmt11pgc/1/)

---

2. [**CSS Transition:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

   **CSS:**

   ```
   #container {
       position: relative;
       overflow: hidden;
       height: 500px;
   }
   #hv {
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       top: 100px;
       width: 100%;
       height: 120px;
       margin-left: -100%;
       background-color: green;
       -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
       transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
       z-index: 10;
   }
   ```

   Then you'll only need to change the `margin-left` in jQuery:

   ```
   $("#navi li").hover(function(e){
       if((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < $(this).width() / 2)
           $('#hv').css('margin-left', '0px');
       else
           $('#hv').css('margin-left', '0px');
   }, function(e){
       if((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < $(this).width() / 2)
           $('#hv').css('margin-left', '-100%');
       else
           $('#hv').css('margin-left', '100%');
   });
   ```

   [**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/zxfaz0kr/2/)

Comment: Thx bro, but how do I stop de animation? I tried it with .stop() after the .find but then the #hv turns to right and to the left...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Stop as so when you hover there'll be no more slides? If yes then use `$("#navi li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');` wherever you want. onclick or keypress, etc

Comment: I used the jquery version. when you enter and leave a "li" than it only makes the hide slide. I added a .stop(true, true) before the hides and shows.